# How do I check if a client's socket InputStream contains data?

Tags: java, inputstream

I want to check if the InputStream buffer contains any data which it can read and output without having to initially call `readLine()` and waiting for data.

I have looked into `available()` but this didn't seem to work as it always output 0.

```
        while (true)
    {
        fromServer = in.readLine(); //Causing a hang waiting for reply
        System.out.println(fromServer);

        if ((fromUser = stdIn.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            out.println(fromUser);
            fromServer = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(fromServer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you give some informatiom about your program, e.g. some source code? Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: I am trying to develop a car park management system. A queue is formed when cars are trying to enter but the car park is full. Members from this queue are removed when car exits. The issue is readLine causes the client to get stuck hanging for a server reply if access isn't permitted for the client

Answer (score 0):

`available()` might tell you the number of *bytes* available, if implemented, but nothing can tell you whether there is a complete *line* other than trying to read it.

You need to read in a separate thread.

> The issue is `readLine()` causes the client to get stuck hanging for a server reply if access isn't permitted for the client.

So the issue is really that the server should *send* something 'if access isn't permitted for the client', i.e. a message that says so, rather than doing nothing. You can't use absence of a message as a message in a blocking I/O system.

You also need to check *every* `readLine()` result for null, and if you get it when reading a socket you need to close it.

Comment: In fact if access isn't permitted for the client why is the server keeping the connection open?

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Instance of [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) and call available on that object:

```
InputStream is = ...;
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
if (bis.available() == 0) {
    // do sth if input is available
}
```

I tried it with a little server-client application, it worked for me.

**EDIT**: Type mismatch gone.
As the Java Documentation says, the InputStream.available() *always* returns zero. In comparison to that, the BufferedInputStream returns „[the number of bytes remaining that can be read in the buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#available())“

Comment: `BufferedInputStream` does not have the magical property of making an `available()` method that previously returned zero not do so.

Comment: There is a type mismatch, cannot convert int to boolean

Comment: 1. `InputStream` is an abstract class. The `InputStream` returned by `Socket.getInputStream()` isn't, and it can implement `available()` without returning zero. 2. The *complete* documentation of `BufferedInputStream.available()`, which you have only partially quoted, states that it returns the number of bytes remaining in the buffer *plus* whatever is returned by the `available()` method of its nested stream. In the code you posted, the `BufferedInputStream` has never been read into, so there is never anything in its buffer in the first place, so it doesn't magically solve the OP's problem.